# Never Used Compact Closure...

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, then $X$ is regular.
>
> Proof: Suppose that $x$ is some point not in the closed set $C$. Then $x$ is in the open set $C^c$, and $X$ being LCH implies there exists an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq \overline {U} \subseteq C^c$, where $\overline{U}$ is compact. Taking the complement, we get $C \subseteq \overline{U}^c$, and obviously $U \cap \overline{U}^c = \emptyset$.

Something about this seems fishy, especially since I never used the fact that $U$ has compact closure.

For completeness, we know:

> **Theorem 29.2:** Let $X$ be Hausdorff. Then $X$ is locally compact if and only if given $x\in X$, and given a neighborhood $U$ of $X$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and $\overline V\subseteq U.$

Comment: _How_ does LCH imply the existence of such a $U$? (You must use at least some compactness in that, since not all Hausdorff spaces are regular.)

Comment: How do we know that $\overline{U}\subseteq C^c$ just because $\overline U$ is compact? All we know is that there is an open set $V$ containing $X$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact. Setting $U=V\cap C^c$ gives that $\overline{U}$ is also compact, but it doesn't show that $\overline{U}\subseteq C^c.$

Comment: But you are correct that it is enough to show such a $U$ exists.

Comment: @DanielFischer Theorem 29.2: "Let $X$ be Hausdorff. Then $X$ is locally compact if and only if given $x \in X$, and given a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact and $\overline{V} \subseteq U$." From this theorem, I get my set $U$ such that $\overline{U} \subseteq C^c$, but I figured that $\overline{U}$ being compact would be used in the proof somewhere.

Comment: Then everything interesting happened in the proof of 29.2. That theorem says that a Hausdorff space is locally compact if and only if the compact neighbourhoods form a neighbourhood basis at each point. A Hausdorff space is regular if and only if the closed neighbourhoods form a neighbourhood basis at each point (depending on the used nomenclature, that may not need the Hausdorffness restriction). Since compact subsets are closed in Hausdorff spaces, the implication is direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you know Theorem 29.2, then what you are using for local compactness is just that $U$ exists such that $\overline{U}\subseteq C^c.$

While you aren't using that $\overline U$ is compact, it is not true in general that $U$ exists if you don't have local compactness of $X.$

Indeed, "regular" can be seen as equivalent to:

> Given any $x\in X$ and any neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $X$ such that $\overline{U}\subseteq V.$

So Theorem 29.2 is stating that, for Hausdorff spaces, local compactness is a stronger form of this definition, with the added requirement that $\overline{U}$ is compact. The proof of 29.2 contains all the hard work.

---

(Correction: Contrary to my claim in prior versions of this document, this can all proceed "at $x$," rather than requiring global properties. Here's the outline.)

Interestingly, if we define "Hausdorff," "locally compact," and "regular" at a point as:

> $X$ is "locally compact at $x$" if there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact.

and:

> $X$ is "regular at $x$" if, for any closed set $C$ not containing $x$, there exists disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $x\in U, C\subseteq V.$

and:

> $X$ is "Hausdorff at $x$" if, for any $y\neq x$ there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ with $x\in U$ and $y\in V.$

Then we get the following version of $29.2$:

> Theorem 29.2-L: Given that $X$ is Hausdorff at $x$, then $X$ is locally compact at $x$ if and only if for any open neighborhood $V$ of $x$, we have an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact and $\overline{U}\subseteq V.$
>
> Proof: Let $W$ be the neighborhood of $x$ such that $\overline{W}$ is compact.
> Let $U_1=W\cap V.$ Let $C=\overline{U_1}\cap V^c$, which is a closed subset of the compact $\overline U$ and hence compact.
>
> For each $y\in C$, find a neighborhood $W_y$ of $y$ such that $x\not\in\overline{W_y}.$ (You can find such $W_y$ because $X$ is Hausdorff at $x.$)
>
> Then $\{W_y\}_{y\in C}$ is an open cover of $C$, so there are $y_1,\dots, y_n$ such that $W_{y_1}\cup\cdots\cup W_{y_n}$ covers $C$.
>
> Now let $U=U_1\setminus\left(\overline{W_{y_1}}\cup\cdots\cup\overline{W_{y_n}}\right).$
>
> We know that $U$ is open and contains $x$ and is a subset of $W$, so $\overline{U}$ must be compact.
>
> The last step is to prove that $\overline{U}\subseteq V.$ But $\overline{U}$ is contained in the closed set $\overline{U_1}\setminus\left(W_{y_1}\cup\cdots\cup W_{y_n}\right)$ which can't contain any elements of $V^c$, since any element in $\overline{U_1}\cap V^c=C$ is necessarily in some $W_{y_i}.$